# XML layout overlapping text issue

Tags: android, layout

I used relativelayout and here is what I've got. I can't get the image to fill the section I want. I don't know how to fix it. I've heard something about using layout weight, is that some thing I should use?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:background="@drawable/background">


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imagehome"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/tvtitle1"
    android:src="@drawable/one" />

   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtitle1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"         
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Voted Best Dentist five years running by"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#9D4F1B"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvtitle2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"/>


   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvtitle2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="The Oakland Tribune"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:textColor="#9D4F1B"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvhome"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvhome"
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="     You&apos;ll be cared for by our highly trained staff of dental professionals,energized to work as a team while providing the highest quality of care for your dental health. We offer complete dentistry for the entire family at a single location.                                                           "
        android:textColor="#4C2016"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/special"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/special"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/cc"
        android:text="Specials"
        android:textColor="#F6E6C6"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tvbutton"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp" />


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="App provided by Bay Area Dental Marketing"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />



 </RelativeLayout>
```

on the xml file,

[image]

and on the device

[image]

It got better but it'snot there yet!

Comment: I just edited what I've got considering the suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When working with multiple screen sizes, I have found it best practice to either (a) use [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html), or (b) set a [LinearLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) inside a [ScrollView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html).

Comment: @Mona, `RelativeLayout` lets you specify a item's location based on other items on screen. If you are using `Eclipse`, begin typing the attribute `android:`, then wait for it to load a list of possible attributes. If you type `align`, you will get a list of the attributes you are likely to want to use.

Comment: @Mona you need to remove all the `margin`-related attributes from the `ImageView`.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how much flexibility you have but the best solution would be to remove the text and image from the background and add them as views instead.  As you have experienced unless each piece is added as a view it is nearly impossible to guarantee it will look correct on all devices.

Answer (score 1):

Use RelativeLayout so you won't have to specify the pixels.

Alternativley if you are doing that for one particular phone select corresponding screen size in the XML designer in Eclipse. Yet, using RelativeLayout guarantees it will work on all the phones

Comment: I'm not sure how to use relativelayout. Do I just replace the linear layout with relativelayout? or I have to change some stuff on the items in the page also. I would be nice if you can explain more. thanks

Comment: I wouldn't be able to explain as good as do books such as 'Pro Android' and many other books and as explained on Google site and on many internet resources.

Answer (score 1):

Even using the suggested answers above you may still run into problem on different size screens. The best solution I can think of is to create separate image resources for the background and foreground then add an image view with the foreground image as the source.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >
<!-- This method makes this layout redundant, dont need this anymore 
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="23dip"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="255dip" 
    android:orientation="vertical" >-->


<!-- put the foreground image in an imageview -->
<ImageView  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="@drawable/foregroundImage"/>


<TextView
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="132dp"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="some text"
    android:textColor="#4C2016"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/special"
    android:layout_width="131dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/cc"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
    android:layout_marginLeft="75dip"
    android:textSize="17dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Specials"
    android:textColor="#F6E6C6" />
</LinearLayout>
```